# Overwriting object with new object of same type and using closure using this

Tags: c++, this, undefined-behavior

In the following code an object is overwritten with a new object of same type, where a lambda-expression creates a closure that uses `this` of the old object. The old address (`this`) remains the same, the new object has the same layout, so this should be ok and not UB. But what about non trivial objects or other cases?

```
struct A {
    void g(A& o, int v) {
        o = A{.x = v, .f = [this]{
            std::cout << "f" << this->x << '\n';
        }};
    }
    int x{0};
    std::function<void()> f;
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "dtor" << x << '\n';
    }
};

void test() {
    A a;
    a.g(a, 2);
    a.f();
}
```

Comment: Looks legal for any types.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8K9MxWxK6

Comment: Lifetime of `a` is well define `this` from lambda refers to `a` inside `test`, when`f` is called captured `this` remains valid. So no problems here.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Probably you are trying introduce a danger that lambda can impact lifetime of captured by ref or pointers objects, but this code doesn't have this issue.

Comment: This was just a question that arises from another example. No special use case. I just wasn't sure about it. But I find it awkward anyway. Thanks for yout effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually replacing any object. You are just *assigning* from another object to the current one. `o =`  simply calls the implicit copy assignment operator which will copy-assign the individual members from the temporary `A` constructed in the assignment expression with `A{...}`.

The lambda is going to capture `this` from `this` in `g`, not from the temporary object.

`std::function` will always keep a copy of the lambda referring to the original object on which `g` was called and since that is its parent object, it cannot outlive it.

So there is no problem here. The only exception would be that you call `f` during the destruction of the `A` object, in which case using the captured pointer may be forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified code with a corner case. I create a temporary in a function and call `g` on it passing it a more *permanent* object. The temporary vanishes and the long life object now has a closure refering to an object after its end of life. Invoking `f` is UB:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    void g(A& o, int v) {
        o = A{ .x = v, .f = [this] {
            std::cout << "f" << this->x << ' ' << this << '\n';
        } };
    }
    int x{ 0 };
    std::function<void()> f;
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "dtor" << x <<  ' ' << this << '\n';
    }
};

void test(A& a) {
    A b{ 2 };
    b.g(a, 3);
}

int main() {
    A a{ 1 };
    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
    test(a);
    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
    a.f();   // UB because a.f uses an object after its end of life
}
```

The output is:

```
1
dtor3 0135F9C0
dtor2 0135FA30
3
f341072 0135FA30
dtor3 0135FAA8
```

proving that the invocation of `a.f()` tried to use the object at address 0135FA30 (in that specific run) after it has been destroyed.